# Changing service ownership in CentOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, centos7

I have installed Jenkins as root on my CentOS 7 machine.
The installation is complete and Jenkins is running successfully.

I also have another user of the same CentOS 7 machine **user1**
Now next time when I reboot the machine, I want the Jenkins to run as user1 and not as root.

Is this possible?

PS: There were reasons I had to install it as **root** and not as **user1**.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have 50 reputation to leave a comment for you.
But I saw an article relate to your situation. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347358/how-to-change-service-user-in-centos-7